# Table lookup alternative to if - then - else if block

Tags: c++

I am writing some logic like this:

I need to process or skip a section of code based on 2 specific messages (string values)
The string messages are basically a category, and a subcategory

So the logic is like this:
Assume that we are NOT going to process block
If the category == XXX or YYY or ... then look at the subcategory
If subcategory matches pretedermined list then do NOT process block

Basically - it is an opt-in only for certain categories, and only if the sub-category does not match a predetemined "blocking" subcategory

This is easy to implement with if/then/else - but I am trying to make the code easier to update and maintain as we add categories and subcategories to the logic.

At most I would guess there might be 10-15 categories, which each category containing 5-10 "blocking" sub-categories. category and subcategory are std::string

Here is pseudocode:

```
bool process = false;  //assume we are skipping block

if ( category == "XXX")
{
    process = true;
    if (( subcategory == "A")  || (subcategory == "B"))
    {
           process = false;
    }
}
else if (category == "YYY")
}
   process = true;
   if (( subcategory == "C")  || (subcategory == "D") || (subcategory == "E"))
   {
          process = false;
   }
}       

if (process)
{
    // Execute this code block
}
```

So - the only way that we are going to process the block is if these 2 conditions are met

1. Category is included in list
2. Subcategory for that specific Category is NOT in list

I was wanting to make a table or some other data structure that might make this easier to maintain. Any ideas on how to implement this to make it easy to update the table as new categories and subcategories are needed?

Thanks

Comment: How many sub-categories may there be in all? Because you might consider using a simple mapping between string and id, thus only ever using strings at the boundary.

Comment: Probably 10-15 Categories, with each category having 5-10 subcategories....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging around - here is my final code that works well, and it much more maintainable. 
If you have any more suggestions or improvements, let me know

Thanks for the comments and suggestions above - they got me thinking in different directions which ultimately led me to this solution.

-mleega

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using std::find;

...snip...

      std::string strCategoryName;
      std::string strSubCategoryName;

      std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> mCategoryMap;

      mCategoryMap["Category-A"];
      mCategoryMap["Category-A"].push_back("A1");
      mCategoryMap["Category-A"].push_back("A2");

      mCategoryMap["Category-B"];
      mCategoryMap["Category-B"].push_back("B1");
      mCategoryMap["Category-B"].push_back("B2");
      mCategoryMap["Category-B"].push_back("B3");

      mCategoryMap["Category-C"];
      mCategoryMap["Category-C"].push_back("C1");
      mCategoryMap["Category-C"].push_back("C2");
      mCategoryMap["Category-C"].push_back("C3");

      if ( mCategoryMap.find( strCategoryName ) != mCategoryMap.end() )  // If the current category is contained in mCategoryMap then Proceed
      {
           if ( std::find(mCategoryMap[strCategoryName].begin(),mCategoryMap[strCategoryName].end(), strSubCategory) == mCategoryMap[strCategoryName].end() )     // If the current Sub-Category is NOT contained in the map then Proceed
           {
               // EXECUTE CODE BLOCK
           }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can divide this into methods for better maintainence. What I would do is:-

```
bool isProcessableCategory(std::string category);
```

This would return true for all category for which you want processing enabled. And false for all other categories.

```
bool isProcessbleSubCategory(std::string category, std::string subCategory);
```

would then check for specifec sub-category.

This way you would localize all the changes to these functions only.